# How to use Double.TryParse Method (String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider, Double)

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to try parse a longitude that has the value "-51.739253997802734".

```
var unknownGeoCoordinate = GeoCoordinate.Unknown;
double latitude;
double longitude;
var numberFormatInfo = new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = ".", NegativeSign = "\u2212", NumberNegativePattern = 1 };
const NumberStyles style = NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign | NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint;

if (!double.TryParse(latLng.First(), style, numberFormatInfo, out latitude) || !double.TryParse(latLng.Last(), style, numberFormatInfo, out longitude))
    return unknownGeoCoordinate;
```

The condition

```
double.TryParse(latLng.Last(), style, numberFormatInfo, out longitude)
```

always returns false and longitude is not set. It only happens for strings prefixed with "-".

Comment: Are you sure about that NumberNegativeSign? shouldn't it be a plain `'-'`?

Comment: What is `latLng.First()`?

Comment: NegativeSign = "\u2212" surely was a wrong guess.  Remove that and try again.

Answer (score 7):

You are specifically setting the NumberNegativeSign to "\u2212". This may be the official Unicode Minus Sign, but is not what is usually used in programming languages or data communication.

Your example *does* parse when I use a plain "-" (\u002D, Hyphen-minus). Your parsing failed because the negative sign in the input was not what you specified.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use the following:

```
double d;
double.TryParse("-3.1415", NumberStyles.Any, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out d);
```

Which ignores all regional settings and uses the format which is used in most cases.

Comment: Probably answers the question, but would be interesting to see why the posted example fails.

Comment: @StevenJeuris You are right. How to use the method is asked, not how the workaround goes ;-). This may still be helpful though.

Answer (score 2):

This solved my problem

```
private new const NumberStyles Style = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign;
```

Apparently NumberStyles.Number screwed something up.

Edit:
Found out I could make it much more simpler

```
private new const NumberStyles Style = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign;

var value = GetValue();
var unknownGeoCoordinate = GeoCoordinate.Unknown;

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
    return unknownGeoCoordinate;

// The value of location in the Sitecore field is a pipe-separated string
// the first value is the latitude followed by pipe "|", then longitude
// Example: 67.2890989|14.401694
var latLng = value.Split(new[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

if (latLng.Count() != 2)
    return unknownGeoCoordinate;

double latitude;
double longitude;

if (!double.TryParse(latLng.First(), Style, null, out latitude) || !double.TryParse(latLng.Last(), Style, null, out longitude))
return unknownGeoCoordinate;
```

It would probably also work with

```
private new const NumberStyles Style = NumberStyles.Any;
```

Thanks for your answers.

Best,
Bilal

Answer (score 0):

```
var numberFormatInfo = new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = ".", NegativeSign = "\u002d", NumberNegativePattern = 1 };
```

works.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2245138/12682

> You'll probably want to use the true minus sign, Unicode codepoint
>   \u2212. The minus sign you use in programming (\u002d) is a
>   "hyphen-minus", its collation order is context sensitive because it is
>   also frequently used as a hyphen. There's more than you'll want to
>   know about the many different kind of dashes in [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash).