# Array.sort and Linq OrderBy give different results

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, sorting

I am trying to do sort an array in C# and in javascript. But I am having a problem that both the sort results are not matching. They both sort differently for example if the input array have underscores.

in C# below is a sample code and [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QXlE0a) is a dotnetfiddle link.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var array= new string[]{"Meter_2","Meter0Add","Meter0Replace","Meter_1","ZZZ"};

        var temp= array.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();

        foreach(string x in temp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }

    }
}
```

result:
Meter_1, 
Meter_2, 
Meter0Add, 
Meter0Replace, 
ZZZ

in javascript below is a code sample [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/adgptkvj/364/) is a js fiddle link.

```
var array  = ["Meter_2","Meter0Add","Meter0Replace","Meter_1","ZZZ"];
array.sort();
document.writeln(array.join(", "));
```

result
Meter0Add, 
Meter0Replace,
Meter_1,
Meter_2,
ZZZ

The question is how can I make the javascript the same as the C#?

Comment: Culture sensitive (C#) and ordinal (JS) comparison are different - if you use `Ordinal` for compare in C# you'll get same results (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244480/string-comparison-in-net-vs). I can't find good duplicate so - hopefully someone will (or just type same explanation again).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JS [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) has a default sort order, and is not stable, unless supplied with a compare function. According to MDN:

> The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns
>   the array. The sort is not necessarily stable. The default sort order
>   is according to string Unicode code points.

If you'll use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) as a compare function, you'll get the same results:

```js
var array = ["Meter_2", "Meter0Add", "Meter0Replace", "Meter_1", "ZZZ"];
array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.localeCompare(b);
});
console.log(array.join(", "));
```

---

**Note:** You can find more info in this article - [Sorting - We're Doing It Wrong](http://blog.rodneyrehm.de/archives/14-Sorting-Were-Doing-It-Wrong.html)