# Why does my sorting algorithm not correctly sort all of my values in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have created a sorting algorithm to sort an array in my program. The algorithm sorts most of the array fine, however a few of the values near the end of the array arent in the correct position at all.

```
string temp;
int counter = 0;
do
{
    for (int i = 0; i < low256.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < low256.Length; j++)
        {
            counter += 1;
            if (string.Compare(low256[i], low256[j]) == -1)
            {
                temp = low256[i];
                low256[i] = low256[j];
                low256[j] = temp;
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
    }
} while (counter <= 255);

foreach(string value in low256)
{
    Console.Write(value + " ");
}
```

This is what is printed to the console after running the program:

```
-9.7067  -8.6887  -8.0983  -8.0075  -7.9666  -7.9489  -7.6039  -7.5488  
-7.3513  -6.9742  -6.9052  -6.8570  -6.7794  -6.7452  -6.6020  -6.5882  
-6.4784  -6.3746  -6.3607  -6.3009  -6.2648  -6.1930  -6.1609  -5.9756  
-5.9369  -5.9168  -5.8945  -5.8634  -5.7830  -5.7047  -5.6102  -5.5937  
-5.5481  -5.5326  -5.4321  -5.1973  -5.1795  -5.1056  -5.0968  -5.0614  
-5.0608  -4.9593  -4.8816  -4.8364  -4.8080  -4.7547  -4.7408  -4.7365  
-4.7127  -4.7031  -4.5894  -4.5882  -4.5257  -4.4337  -4.4300  -4.4292  
-4.4101  -4.3792  -4.3786  -4.3208  -4.3167  -4.2972  -4.2907  -4.1644  
-4.1373  -4.1147  -4.1108  -4.1058  -4.1052  -4.0797  -4.0521  -4.0468  
-4.0301  -4.0268  -4.0207  -4.0183  -4.0053  -3.9670  -3.9084  -3.8817  
-3.7977  -3.7881  -3.7660  -3.7522  -3.7302  -3.7159  -3.7108  -3.6910  
-3.6878  -3.6477  -3.6458  -3.5687  -3.5389  -3.5337  -3.4929  -3.4872  
-3.4664  -3.4661  -3.4490  -3.4167  -3.4156  -3.4129  -3.4128  -3.4052  
-3.3939  -3.3758  -3.3587  -3.3560  -3.3456  -3.3152  -3.2829  -3.2744  
-3.1604  -3.1455  3.1389  -3.0993  -3.0205  -3.0090  -3.0059  -2.9945  
-2.9888  -2.9774  -2.9658  -2.9553  -2.9482  -2.8881  -2.8579  -2.8461  
-2.8410  -2.8053  -2.7924  -2.7467  -2.7309  -2.6911  -2.6730  -2.6556  
 2.6365  -2.6039  -2.5892  -2.5890  -2.5782  -2.5590  -2.5356  -2.4829  
-2.4732  -2.4509  -2.4489  -2.4485  -2.4439  -2.4173  -2.4172  -2.4146  
-2.3862  -2.3849  -2.3792  -2.3264  2.3110  -2.3061  -2.3004  -2.2941  
-2.2638  -2.2634  -2.2483  -2.2432  -2.2276  -2.2249  -2.1916  -2.1864  
-2.1530  -2.1132  -2.0508  -2.0225  -2.0215  -2.0099  1.9737  -1.9679  
 1.9267  -1.9198  -1.8669  -1.8634  -1.8601  -1.8265  -1.8077  -1.8073  
-1.7836  -1.7579  -1.7535  -1.7461  -1.7441  -1.7276  -1.6917  -1.6747  
 1.6397  -1.6188  -1.6033  -1.5840  -1.5717  -1.5640  -1.5091  -1.5078  
-1.4936  1.4928  -1.4872  -1.4680  -1.4533  1.4052  -1.3884  -1.3876  
-1.2864  -1.2753  1.2380  -1.2229  -1.1996  -1.1638  -1.1551  1.1389  
-1.0769  -1.0610  -0.9981  -0.9516  -0.8525  0.8319  -0.8293  0.7427  0.7006  
 0.6687  -0.6509  0.6507  -0.6426  -0.5913  0.5592  0.5588  -0.5507  -0.5409  
-0.5287  -0.5132  -0.4933  -0.4753  -0.4281  0.4236  -0.4180  0.4096  - 
 0.3986  -0.3790  0.3696  -0.3360  -0.2987  0.2985  -0.2915  0.2743  0.2053  
 0.1976  0.1418  -0.1022  -0.0594  0.0357
```

As you can see it returns the array with some of the values in the wrong position such as 0.4236 being put before -0.4180.

Comment: These are actually strings and not numbers ?? ://///

Comment: What is item type of `low256`? Is it string? And does all items in `low256` are actualy float/double in string presentation? If all answers is "yes" just use `double.Parse` and compare items as numbers

Comment: Yes low256 is a string array. Where should I put double.Parse in my code sorry?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with the results of the sort - looks perfectly fine for what you've coded up - you obviously confirmed that `string.Compare("0.4236", "-0.4180") == string.Compare("0.4236", "0.4180")` is true (as `-` is ignored by default string comparisons) as well as are happy with `"12" < "2"` since you pick string comparison. This is probably duplicate of some ["C# - why '-' ignored in string comparison"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244480/string-comparison-in-net-vs) - unless you actually looking to sort numbers...

Comment: Yes I was trying to sort numbers, but I couldn't change the data type to decimal for example, because I get a System.Format exception and I can not use a simple operator such as <, because it can not be used to compare a string data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your inner loop you can parse items you need to compare:

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < low256.Length; j++)
{
    counter += 1;
    var a = double.Parse(low256[i]);
    var b = double.Parse(low256[j]);
    if (a.CompareTo(b) == 1) // change to -1 to order by descending
    // rest of code
```

If this is not a homework use linq:

```
low256 = low256
  .Select(double.Parse)
  .OrderBy(x => x)
  .Select(x => x.ToString("0.0000"))
  .ToArray();
```

Also it is bad idea to do some sort on numerics in string presentation. So it would be better to convert all items in `low256` to doubles first and then do what you need

Comment: Thankyou for helping a newbie out Aleks, I will remember this for the future in my coding projects.